# listings \def problem

Tags: listings

When I complile the following code with xelatex, `%\end{lstlisting}` is a necessary line to prevent error. What is the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, onecolumn, openany,]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English please
%\usepackage[final]{microtype} % Less badboxes
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newfontfamily{\lstcode}[Scale=0.85]{Ubuntu Mono}
\lstdefinestyle{csharp}
{
     language=[Sharp]C,
     frame=shadowbox,
     rulecolor=\color{white!80!black},
     rulesepcolor=\color{white!80!black},
     basicstyle=\lstcode,
     showstringspaces=false,     
     breaklines=true
}

\def\bcsh#1\ncsh
{
    \lstset{style=csharp}
    \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
    #1
    \end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}
\bcsh
class Program
{  
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
\ncsh
%\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot pass a `lstlisting` as the argument to a macro.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It might be very fascinating to define shortcuts for environments, but most times they fail due to specific needs of the environment. And `lstlisting` is more cunning than `tabular` etc. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't pass a `lstlisting` environment as the argument to a macro.

You can define a new environment, instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, onecolumn, openany,]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English please
%\usepackage[final]{microtype} % Less badboxes
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newfontfamily{\lstcode}[Scale=0.85]{Ubuntu Mono}
\lstdefinestyle{csharp}
{
     language=[Sharp]C,
     frame=shadowbox,
     rulecolor=\color{white!80!black},
     rulesepcolor=\color{white!80!black},
     basicstyle=\lstcode,
     showstringspaces=false,     
     breaklines=true
}

\lstnewenvironment{bcsh}[1][]
 {\lstset{style=csharp,numbers=left,#1}}
 {}

\begin{document}
\begin{bcsh}
class Program
{  
    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
\end{bcsh}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`.

Comment: @iranano With that very example?

Comment: Yes. With your code that error is shown.

Comment: @iranano Check whether some invisible character got inserted during the paste on your system. I copied the code in a fresh file and it gives no problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. A few more characters were copied. sorry.